# What is this MongoDb Error: Expected 'query' to be BSON (or equivalent), but got bson.ObjectId instead

Tags: mongodb, typegoose

I have a `nest.js` + `mongodb` + `typegoose` app.

I get the following error:

> Expected 'query' to be BSON (or equivalent), but got bson.ObjectId instead.

In `deleteById` method:

```
export abstract class BaseService<T extends Typegoose> {
  protected _model: ModelType<T>;

  //............other methods............

  async deleteById(id: string): Promise<DocumentType<T>> {
    // ERROR IN THIS LINE >>
    return this._model.findOneAndDelete(id).exec();
  }
}
```

NOTE: The passed `id` is a valid `id` in database.

Answer (score 2):

The `findOneAndDelete` function requires a BSON document as an argument.

Try

```
findOneAndDelete({_id:id})
```